# TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduce_retracing' - Tensorflow version issue? Setting up head2toe repository from github

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to setup the google research head2toe repository (https://github.com/google-research/head2toe)

I followed the setup steps in the readme and when I do the step of
'bash run.sh', it does a bunch of stuff and eventually I get the following error:

TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduce_retracing'

---

Am I messing up or is this repository broken? Are any of you able to get it to work?

I tried:

- Changing tensorflow versions (even though the requirements.txt specifically uses 2.7)
- Using old versions of the other packages in case they no longer work with tf 2.7

This is my first time trying to clone and replicate a complex repo's results so if anyone is able to figure out how to setup and run this based on the instructions, it would be appreciated. I am working through a remote cluster's terminal which I am trying to get used to since there is no visual interface so any suggestions on where/how I can view the results from this setup would be a great help too but mainly concerned with it all working first.

(I also tried running it all in my own machine but the same issues occurr so I don't think it's an issue with the remote terminal.)

Thanks

Comment: Hardly a `git` question.

Comment: Try installing in a new virtual environment. Also try using an older version of Python.